# Microsoft Sql Server - How to replicate a table from Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, replication, linked-server

I have an Origin Database - #1 with very restrictive access due to security.

I provisioned a new Windows desktop machine with Microsoft Sql Server Management where I created a local database with all privileges, so I can create a Linked Server to database #1.

I have access to the Database #1 via Linked Server but I need to replicate some tables in realtime; I tried using the Replication option in the Object Explorer, but it does not allow me to do anything with the Linked Server.

How can I replicate some of those tables via Linked Server? So, I can copy those tables and updates and store them in local database?

Comment: Are you looking to create a 'recent enough' backup to do testing on or to have a constantly updating backup that mirrors the production db?

If you just want to pull what is currently up there, you could just drop the tables locally and run something like 
`Select * into tbl1
From Database1.server.dbo.tbl1`

Comment: I think recent enough is good. But I'm not using as a backup, I'm using the replication database as read-only for other apps to access the data. There's some other restrictions to the database #1 so that's why it's cumbersome.

Comment: @ThomasD. just saw your suggestion. Well, it cannot be select * into. My concept of recent enough is like every 15 minutes to 1 hour. So if we keep dropping and creating a new table into the database, I'm not sure if that's going to fit the requirements.

Comment: I apologize, when I said "backup" I just meant "local copy of a table." if you're just looking for a one-off query to run so that the other apps have somewhat up-to-date info, then my first suggestion will work, if you're looking to automate this and have it run every x hours or something, then it becomes a lot more involved. Is there any reason that you couldn't create a user on Database1 with very low permissions such that they are effectively read-only? It seems that creating another database will not be the optimal solution.

Comment: @ThomasD. there are concerns about Database #1 which is behind a VPN that may or may not connect due to constant security changes on that VPN channel. So the idea is to make a "copy of a copy", as badly it sounds unfortunately, so in case the VPN connection drops, we are still able to have the "latest version".

Comment: Are you willing / able to install and use external synchronization software? If so, you could use a tool such as SQL Database Studio. I have never used it, but from what I have read, it will allow you to create automatic synchronization scripts and run them as a stored procedure. Otherwise, you could set up a trigger or follow some of Randi's other suggestions. I don't think there is a super nice and friendly option here, given the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like any of the built-in SQL features are going to meet your needs here:

- SQL replication makes a lot of changes to the source db, and probably won't work over a linked server
- Mirroring and/or always-on availability groups likewise require lots of underlying configuration to the source server
- Log shipping, if you had access to transaction log backups, would bring over the entire database state, not just the tables you want

You're going to have to either use a 3rd-party software (like [Redgate SQL Compare](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/index)), or roll your own.

Personally I'd build an SSIS package to pull down new or updated data from the required tables (hopefully you have some easy "last_update" fields to go off of) and run it via a SQL job every few minutes. There is no SQL wizard for this, you'll have to know what you're doing or hire someone who does.